# Validação customizada Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

Oi, pessoal! Sou nova em Laravel e queria tirar uma dúvida sobre as validações.

Esse é meu controller. Quando eu chamo o `Validator`, eu estou passando o arrays para rules, messages e attributes.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Validators\ContatoValidator;
use App\Models\Contato;

class FaleConoscoController extends Controller
{
    private $app;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->app= App::getFacadeRoot();
    }

    public function send(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ContatoValidator::rules, ContatoValidator::messages, ContatoValidator::attributes);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response() -> json($validator->errors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }else{
            //$model = 
        }
    }
}
```

Abaixo a minha classe ContatoValidator com os arrays:

```
namespace App\Validators;

class ContatoValidator{

        const rules = [
            'mensagem' => 'required|max:500',
            'assunto' => 'required|max:255',
            'remetente.nome' => 'required|max:255',
            'remetente.email' => 'required|max:255|email',
            'remetente.estado' => 'nullable|max:255',
            'remetente.cidade' => 'nullable|max:255',
        ];

        const messages = [
            'required'=> 'O campo :attribute não foi preenchido',
            'same'    => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
            'max'     => 'O campo :attribute deve ter no máximo :max caracteres.',
            'between' => 'The :attribute value :input is not between :min - :max.',
            'in'      => 'The :attribute must be one of the following types: :values',
            'email'   => 'O e-mail inserido não é válido.'
        ];

        const attributes = [
            'remetente' => [
                'nome' => 'nome',
                'email' => 'email',
                'estado' => 'estado',
                'cidade' => 'cidade',
            ],
        ];

    }
```

Eu quero que `remetente.nome` retorne como apenas `nome`. E assim por diante nos outros atributos de remetente.

Porem, o resultado é o seguinte:

```
{
    "assunto": [
        "O campo assunto não foi preenchido"
    ],
    "remetente.nome": [
        "O campo remetente.nome não foi preenchido"
    ],
    "remetente.email": [
        "O campo remetente.email não foi preenchido"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Se pode postar o seu formulário?

Comment: Não fiz formulário, estou fazendo a requisição via postman:

Comment: `{
   "remetente": {
      "email": "",
      "cidade": "Vitória",
      "estado": "Espírito Santo"
      
   },
   "assunto": "",
   "mensagem": "Mensagem enviada por e-mail"
}`

Comment: é que tem diferença quando é por form, vou colocar a minha resposta que está certa

Comment: Você precisa ler isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Também é bom ler isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Como explicado na documentação no item [Customização de Erros de Mensagens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-error-messages) precisa fazer as seguintes configurações como descrito na sua pergunta que no caso é para um `rest` (se for `form` no lugar do ponto é um `_`, tem que tomar bastante cuidado), ***exemplo***:

```
namespace App\Validators;

class ContatoValidator{

    const rules = [
        'mensagem' => 'required|max:500',
        'assunto' => 'required|max:255',
        'remetente.nome' => 'required|max:255',
        'remetente.email' => 'required|max:255|email',
        'remetente.estado' => 'nullable|max:255',
        'remetente.cidade' => 'nullable|max:255',
    ];

    const messages = [
        'remetente.nome.required'=> 'O campo nome não foi preenchido',
        'remetente.nome.max'=> 'O campo nome tem que ter no máximo', // etc ...
    ];

    const attributes = [
        'remetente' => [
            'nome' => 'nome',
            'email' => 'email',
            'estado' => 'estado',
            'cidade' => 'cidade',
        ],
    ];

}
```

ou seja, coloque os nome do campo e o tipo de validação e informe a mensagem como explicado no exemplo:

```
'remetente.nome.required'=> 'O campo nome não foi preenchido'
```

para cada validação isso deve ser repetido.

Comment: Então não dá pra usar a mensagem generalizada customizando os atributos quanto preciso referenciar um objeto?

Comment: Essa forma de fazer eu tinha conseguindo, mas aí era muita mensagem igual. Depois descobri que tem como fazer a mensagem referenciando o atributo

Comment: @AnaCarol é assim que deve ser feito já que você quer personalizar...

Comment: Eu queria fazer algo assim: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/validation-nested-attributes-and-nice-names

Comment: O que você postou não tem nada a ver, o que a minha resposta lhe dá é o exemplo claro de como resolver, inclusive tenho que colocar na resposta que isso funciona para web api ...

Comment: Esse aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761230/how-to-set-custom-attribute-labels-for-nested-inputs-in-laravel

Comment: A maneira como você mostrou é um `array` de informações e no seu caso é um objeto ... é diferente por causa disso tem que ser feito como eu te mostrei... @AnaCarol Uma coisa também não é como você quer é como o framework exige!

Comment: Bom, então não dá pra referenciar o atributo na mensagem nesses casos. Tem que escrever uma para cada.

Comment: @AnaCarol como o teu exemplo da pergunta é o que eu coloquei como resposta, então é um objeto se fosse `array` poderia usar esse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393279/nested-array-validation-laravel mas, não é !!! entendeu ... tem que colocar como eu te expliquei na resposta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104111/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-ana-carol).

Comment: Outro exemplo com objeto: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/validating-nested-json?page=1 @AnaCarol